# Why is 扱う in the potential form?

Tags: grammar, potential-form

> この本は日本語の文法の本です。
> 日本語というと、万葉集や源氏物語などの古代の言葉も、日本の各地で話されている方言も、みなすべて日本語ですが、この本で**扱える**のは現代日本の東京の言葉だけです。

I'm reading the preface of an online [book](http://niwanoda.web.fc2.com/bunpou/000maegaki.html). Why is the word in bold in the potential? I assume it means that the Japanese treated in the book is only that of modern Tokyo, but is it not possible to just use 扱う?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> この本で扱えるのは現代日本の東京の言葉だけです

I think the potential form pairs up nicely with だけ. Literally, "In this book, what we **are able** to handle is only the language of modern day Tokyo Japanese", or more naturally "We can only handle the Japanese of modern day Tokyo in this book".  Presumably suggesting that they **couldn't** handle anything else without a much bigger book.

Comment: OMG, I feel so dumb now. I've seen it so many times and not understood it, it's only now that I ask and got an answer. Thanks.